# Matlab Distribution Sampling

Tags: matlab, distribution, sampling, random

How can I create a vector `x` in Matlab that has values between 0.8 and 1.2, randomly sampled from a:
1. Uniform
2. Normal
distribution?

There are a lot of functions dealing with distributions, but I'm having trouble using them properly.

Comment: You need `rand` for uniform distribution, and `randn` for normal distribution. However, any normal distribution is unbounded, so  "normal distrbution" and "0.8 and 1.2" are incompatible requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can use this, for example:

```
y = 0.8 + rand*0.4;
```

this will generate random number between 0.8 and 1.2.
because rand creates uniform distribution I believe that `rand*0.4` creates the same ;)